# Dispatcher on an event by itself and through delegate

Tags: c#, wpf, dispatcher

I have a 3rd party DLL which I receive data from a device through network socket. `Foo_WorkCompleted` is an event subscribed to an action when data is received and is automatically fired. My first try is to check if the thread has been accessed, and if not, call itself again from a new thread to update the UI. But I receive threading exception that it is occupied. Then I tried calling a delegate from the dispatcher, that works.

I do not see difference between the two. An event should just work like a delegate. So, why one works but not the other. Would someone please help explain?

**This does not work (threading exception):**

```
private void Foo_WorkCompleted(object sender, WorkCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
    {
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
        (EventHandler<WorkCompletedEventArgs>)Foo_WorkCompleted, sender, e);
        return;
    }

    SomeMethod();
}
```

**This works:**

```
private delegate void UpdateUIDelegate();

private void Foo_WorkCompleted(object sender, WorkCompletedEventArgs e)
{      
     Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
           DispatcherPriority.Send, new UpdateUIDelegate(SomeMethod));
}
```

Comment: Could you explain the need for calling the event from within...I don't understand in which scenario you need this

Comment: because I am updating the UI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using CheckAccess reversed, if the calling thread is the main thread for the dispatcher it will return true, so you need to do the invoke if it returns false:

```
private void Foo_WorkCompleted(object sender, WorkCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
    {
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
        (EventHandler<WorkCompletedEventArgs>)Foo_WorkCompleted, sender, e);
        return;
    }

    SomeMethod();
}
```

Comment: Omg.. perhaps can you explain the difference between the two, are they essesntially the same?

Comment: Sorry, what do you need to be explained? between two what?

Comment: calling itself on another thread vs. handling it by a new delegate

Comment: That's another matter very different to what you've asked and there are tons of info about it. Anyway, it's very simple, only main thread can update the GUI and the Dispatcher is tied to main thread, so, when you CheckAccess, if the call is done from another thread it will return false, in this case you call Dispatcher.BeginInvoke which will call the delegate on the thread associated to the Dispatcher, in this case main thread.